# Submit form using only PHP? Without JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, forms, post, submit

I have a form

```
<form method='post' action='action.php' name='myForm'>
  <input type='' name='id' value='id'>
  <script>document.myForm.submit();</script>
</form>
```

Can I submit this form without using JavaScript - only PHP without clicking on the submit button, automatically?

This form must be auto submitted on page load, but not using JavaScript (without `onload`)

Comment: Are you wanting it to submit automatically when the page loads?

Comment: You mean, you want to submit it by means of pure HTML? Then there are answers which show you how to do that. Or did you really mean submitting a form with PHP? I.e., server-side?

Comment: you can create an http client in php to submit something with any html involved.

Comment: I'm sure you could do it in Dart?

Comment: Why the down votes? Seems a perfectly reasonable question to me. Anyway, see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

The act of form submission is done on the client side (browser) and has very little to do with PHP (server side).

You could add a submit button like `<input type='submit' value='click here to complete step' />`

Answer (score 4):

A form must be submit,  by the client side.  On client-side, there's only two way: by Javascript or by human (clicking on the submit button).

Comment: php function are server-side ( before the web page send to user). Submitting a form, is done after the user receive the web page

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't send this page to the user, redirect him to the other web page.

Comment: this form include by iframe 1x1 px, they great work by using js, but i heed to do submit this form automatikly in browser without js and object(denied)-just only html and php

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the `<input type="submit" />` like the following:

```
<form method='post' action='action.php' name='myForm'>
  <input type='text' name='id' value='id' />
  <input type='submit' name='submission' value='Submit id'>
</form>
```

Comment: form must be submit on page load, bun i can use js and object

Comment: @user1029691 Why would you want to submit a form on page load?

Answer (score 1):

add a submit button.

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, what you are trying to do is not possible. The best you can do is probably this:

```
<form method='post' action='action.php' name='myForm'>
    <input type='' name='id' value='id'>
    <input type='submit' id='submit-button' />
    <script>domument.getElementByID('submit-button').style.display="none";document.myForm.submit();</script>
</form>
```

A submit button is displayed when client side scripting is disabled. When it's enabled, the submit button is immediately hidden and the form is automatically submitted.

**EDIT**

Or you could simply include the PHP file. `<?php include action.php; ?>`. You won't have access to the `_POST` array, but considering, the client hasn't had chance to enter any data, that won't really matter.