# Auto submit form without javascript

Tags: html, forms, jsp

I have found myself requiring to send some forms automatically in a few key areas of my program to go from one jsp to another using the action attribute. The problem is things such as `<jsp:forward>` do not seem to work as it does not have an "action" attribute, and I can only provide it with a specific page, rather than what I am doing with the action attribute in the form.

In doing so, I have ended up with many of my jsp pages ending like the following:

```
<form name="my_form" action="../some_id" method=post>
</form>        
<script>
    document.my_form.submit(); //automatically submits the form
</script>
```

My problem lies with trying to move away from using javascript.

Essentially, I need an alternate way to run the "action" from the form, as you can see I am not actually using the form to pass any parameters at all.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if I need to provide any additional information or clarification and I will try to reply as soon as I can.

Comment: Fairly similar question to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175945/submit-form-using-only-php-without-javascript). You can't submit a form from the client side without the client the requesting it. You can only use a JavaScript or create a button and have the end-user press it.

Comment: If you're using a server-side resource that requires a POST, you're out of luck. If you are using a GET, you could use a meta-refresh tag to redirect as if the user had submitted, but you'll have to either use a hardcoded URL or use your JSP to prepopulate the query parameters.